# Override of ModelAdmin.save_model not being called

Tags: django, django-admin, modeladmin

I'm using the GenerickStackedInline which is a subclass of InlineModelAdmin which goes to ModelAdmin. When I override save_model method... it's not being called.

```
class LocatedItemStackedInline(generic.GenericStackedInline):
    template = "admin/location_app/located_items/stacked.html"
    model = LocatedItem
    extra = 1
    form = MyModelForm
    raw_id_fields = ('location',)

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        super(LocatedItemStackedInline, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

    def save_form(self, request, form, change):
        import ipdb;ipdb.set_trace()
        super(LocatedItemStackedInline, self).save_form(request, form, change)
```

So, I'm missing something?

Any clue?

Regards

Comment: Found that save_model is being called in contrib.admin.options but still don't know why mine isn't called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that I was overriding the save_model method on the InlineAdmin instead of on the ModelAdmin itself.

Now is being called...

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.save_model

describes the function you're talking about. My best guess is that you're confused about when and where that will be called. Also, are you sure you're actually working with the latest revision?

Edit: I'd guess that inline ModelAdmin objects may behave differently, given their otherwise special status.

Comment: Not really cause I need the request object to use some stuff from hidden fields in the form.

Still why can't I use that? Is documented. Isn't implemented?